# Searching through NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I have a search code which searches using three parameters but i want to pass a single parameter and match it with all three or four or any number of variables in the code.Can any one show me the way forward

```
 ICriteria oCriteria = base.Session.CreateCriteria<Patient>("p").CreateCriteria("User", "u", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.IsDeleted", false)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.IsPatientSignUp", false)).Add(Restrictions.Like("u.FirstName", '%' + data + "%"))

                        .Add(Restrictions.Like("u.LastName", '%' + data + "%")).Add(Restrictions.Like("u.Email", '%' + data + "%"))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Or(cr1, cr2))
                        .AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.Property("p.MedNexusId"))));
                        patient = oCriteria.List<Patient>().Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: BTW using `+ data +` is opening you up against SQL injection

Comment: data is a parameter of string type  earlier i had different variables for firstname,lastname,email etc but now i have a single textbox for all the values and that is data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate gives us a set of basic tools *(Restrictions in this case)* and we can either extend them *(create new `ICriterion`)* or combine them. So we can create common methods like these:

```
// multiple AND
public static AbstractCriterion AllLike(IEnumerable<string> properties, string toCompare)
{
    Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.Conjunction();
    foreach (var name in properties)
    {
        conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Like(name, toCompare, MatchMode.Anywhere));
    }
    return conjunction;
}
// multiple OR
public static AbstractCriterion AnyLike(IEnumerable<string> properties, string toCompare)
{
    Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
    foreach (var name in properties)
    {
        disjunction.Add(Restrictions.Like(name, toCompare, MatchMode.Anywhere));
    }
    return disjunction;
}
```

And now we can call them like:

```
ICriteria oCriteria = ....
var toMatch = new[] {"u.LastName", "u.Email", ...};
criteria.Add(AllLike(toMatch, data));
// or
criteria.Add(AnyLike(toMatch, data));
```

NOTE: the similar implementation is already there `Restrictions.AllEq(IDictionary propertyNameValues)`